# Index not being used optimally

Tags: mysql, indexing, rdbms

I have the query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT talks.*, users.*
FROM (
  SELECT p_talk
  FROM posts WHERE p_user=1
  GROUP BY p_talk
  ORDER BY MAX(p_time) DESC
  LIMIT 30
) AS posts
 JOIN talks
    ON p_talk=t_id
 JOIN users
    ON t_user=u_id
```

I have made an index "history":

```
p_user, p_time, p_talk
```

But I still get the following EXPLAIN output:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    30  
1   PRIMARY talks   eq_ref  PRIMARY,t_user  PRIMARY 4   posts.p_talk    1   
1   PRIMARY users   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   channels.talks.t_user   1   
2   DERIVED posts   ref p_user,history  history 4       39320   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
```

Why does it look through every single post that matches p_user?

**EDIT:**
If I remove GROUP and ORDER, it still shows all 39320 rows in the EXPLAIN output. That confuses me. Why does it estimate that it will go through all rows that match p_user=1, if I tell it to return the first 30?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It needs to look through all posts where `p_user = 1`.  Are you saying that it is looking through all of those or through all the records regardless of `p_user`?

Comment: Row 4 of EXPLAIN show 39320 rows. The table has ~2 million. It looks like it processes the entire index where p_user=1 instead of just the top rows untill it has 30.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, the optimal index for this table would be:

```
p_user, p_talk, p_time
```

The `group by` is evaluated before the `order by`, so that column needs to be in the index first.

I'm not 100% sure that MySQL would take advantage of this index for this query.

EDIT:

If you are confident that you have enough `p_talk` values in, say, the most recent 500 records, then you can use the following with your existing index:

```
FROM (SELECT p_talk
      FROM (SELECT p_talk, p_time
            FROM posts
            WHERE p_user = 1
            ORDER BY p_time DESC
            LIMIT 500
           ) p
      GROUP BY p_talk
      ORDER BY MAX(p_time) DESC
      LIMIT 30
     ) AS posts
```

Comment: But then it will have to go through all p_talk values. I want the last 30 entries without duplicates of p_talk.

Comment: @user3476232 . . . It *has* to go through all the `p_talk` values because you are using a `group by`.

Comment: How do I avoid it? It is a history feature that should return the last `talks` that the user has submitted `posts` to. I GROUP to avoid the same `talks` showing up more than once.

Comment: Im not crazy about that solution. Could I perhaps make a new index for the purpose that will perform better?